# How to get a dynamic list of distinct property values of a list?

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, distinct-values

I am trying to bind a ComboBox control to a list of strings extracted from a list of custom objects.

Here is the object I'm using :

```
public class Operation
{
    public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is binding the combo box used to input a new Operation's Category to the list of distinct categories already existing in a list of Operations.

Example :

List of Operations :

```
{04/12/2010, 100, "Home"}
{05/12/2010, 100, "Home"}
{05/12/2010, 200, "Entertainment"}
```

Available in the auto-complete list of the combobox : "Home", "Entertainment".

Currently, I am able to get a static list of the available categories existing in the list, but I am unable to get the list updated when I add a new Operation to the existing list.

Comment: Yeah, I ended unbind and rebinding as you suggested.

Comment: Working with a `BindingSource` might come up with some other interesting feature as well. I suggest, if you're interested, that you take an eye out this class for future reference so that you may make this object work for you either. Glad I could help anyway! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to unbind and rebind your list for refresh.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to avoid, is there really no other way to handle this ?

Comment: You should then use a `BindingSource` which you will set its `DataSource` property, then assigning this `BindingSource` as your `ComboBox.DataSource`. After you're done, try to work directly with the `CurrencyManager`. For the refresh, you will then need to work with either one of the `Refresh` method from the above-mentioned objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
_combo.ItemsSource = _operationsCollection;
_combo.DisplayMemberPath = "Category";
_combo.Items.Filter = Filter;

private bool Filter(object operationObj)
{
    var operation = (Operation)operationObj;
    var first = _operationsCollection.First(p => p.Category == operation.Category);
    return ReferenceEquals(operation, first);
}
```